# Strange rectangles appearing near beamer blocks or frame titles

Tags: beamer

Suddenly, the blocks and frame titles in my beamer documents have stopped looking right. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institution}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The associated output is below.

[image: A Beamer title page with a strange gray line next to the title block.]

Below I have zoomed in on the right hand side of the block containing the title to show what is bothering me. As you can see, there is an erroneous gray line.

[image: a zoomed in version of the gray line from the previous image]

These little gray or white lines or rectangles show up next to title blocks and regular blocks. They also sometimes show up next to the titles of frames. At times (unlike in this minimal example), they are quite large and noticeable. At other times they appear or disappear as things appear on the frame (so they draw the eye).

I have tried different themes and different desktops and it keeps happening. Has anyone else run into this problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: On my machine I don't see such line. Perhaps try (1) update your packages, and (2) try different viewer/renderer

Comment: I tried updating and that didn't help. I will check on another view though. That's a good idea. Though I'm using Adobe so it seems like that should work...

Comment: Which engine do you use for the compilation?

Comment: The lines/rectangles still show up in Sumatra.

Comment: I'm using pdflatex -recorder.

Comment: What is "suddenly"? Something must have changed.

Comment: Nothing like what you show (Fedora 34, texlive 20200327-30; `pdflatex`, rendered with `xpdf` or `evince`).

Comment: "Suddenly" means it started happening and, to my recollection, wasn't connected to anything logical like a new version of the beamer package. I first noticed it several weeks ago but I thought it was just the one file I was working on at the time (which wasn't very important). Now I'm seeing them everywhere and cannot figure out why. I agree with you that something must have caused it, but I don't know what and I don't know how to figure it out. I've tried everything I can think of and all the suggestions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was temporary bug in beamer and has been solved in

https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/a3de6ba737d98746a60759a1d0b5c3c23c3879f1

You should update to beamer v3.64 or newer

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I just made my own templates. =)

Comment: @DavidPaige You're welcome!